# spread of information in a complex network

Tags: r

I have network

How to make purple and orange vectors find their neighbours only in green?

A code example:

## Select apex for the orange network

```
   for (v in chory_orange)
{
  y<- neighbors(graf,v)
  zarazeni_orange <- c(zarazeni_orange, y-1)
  print(y) 
}
```

## Select apex for the purple network

```
for (v in chory_play)
{

  y<- neighbors(graf,v)
  zarazeni_play <- c(zarazeni_play, y-1)
  print(y)

}
```

## Plot graph

```
V(graf)[zarazeni_orange ]$color <- 'purple'
V(graf)[zarazeni_play ]$color <- 'orange'
plot(graf, vertex.size=8, vertex.label.color="black", edge.color="black", edge.arrow.width=0.4)
```

[image]